# Child list of getStorageDirectory always return null on Android 11

Tags: android, permissions, android-11

I want get child list of `/storage` directory by `targetSdk=30` app.
So, I settings `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` and I created this code.
(I don't plan to distribute this app, so there is no problem granting this permission.)

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

```kotlin
Environment.getStorageDirectory().list() // return null
```

However, as comment in the code, this code will always return null...

Can you please help me?

(I'm not good at English, so going through a translation service. Sorry if it's not clear.)

Comment: You do not have read access to that directory on any version of Android.

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission missing.

Comment: For all Android versions you have read acces to /storage but not for an Android 11 device.

Comment: I forgot to write that I have also granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

As I remember `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is included `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. So, I think there is no problem with just `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Thanks for many comments!
From the comments of each one, I think looks difficult getting child list of '/storage'...

Then, is there documentation anywhere that show can not access `/storage` on Android 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do it, so I used a different method.
The reason I wanted to get the list under `/storage` was to detect an external SD card.
As an alternative, I implemented it to take the `StorageManager` and fetch the directories for which isRemovable is true.
Thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" this line from your code and check permission for scope storage.

You need to take full access of storage so need to take scoped storage for android 11 or upper devices.

Comment: Thanks answer! My application has `Allow access to manage all files` enabled. And, I've already confirmed that `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is working. Because, my application can access anything except `/storage`. I'm sorry, if my answer is off the mark...